# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined when storing component in useState

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store a child component in my useState hook, but every time the Parent component, I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined`

This `props` is being referred to the props in the Child component. I'm not sure why this is happening, since I'm not even rendering the child component.

```
const ParentComponent React:FC = () => {
    const [component, setComp] = React.useState(ChildComponent);

    return <div>Parent</div>
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    return <div>Child</div>
}
```

Comment: can we know why you are passing ChildComponent to  React.useState(ChildComponent)

Comment: Because its part of a larger component that uses tabs to switch between components. The clicked tab gets mapped to the `component` and gets rendered via `React.createElement(component)`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store a child component in useState hook. 
Check out this sample code

https://codesandbox.io/s/child-hooks-props-ihsgs?fontsize=14

Post your minimum runnable code for further assistance.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const tab1 = React.createElement(
        ChildComponent,
        {'name': 'Tab1 1 1 1 1 '}
      );

      const tab2 = React.createElement(
        ChildComponent,
        {'name': 'Tab2 2 2 2 2'}
      )

    const [component, setComp] = React.useState(tab1);

    return <div> <button onClick={() => setComp(tab2) }> Press me to switch Child </button> {component} </div>
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { return <div> This is Property of Children {this.props.name} </div>}
}
```